# Adding class to drupal 7 tabs

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to add two classes to drupal7's primary tab  element. I tried overriding theme_menu_local_tasks by adding this to my template.php:

```
function {{proj}}_menu_local_tasks(&$variables) {
  $output = '';

  if (!empty($variables['primary'])) {
    $variables['primary']['#prefix'] = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('Primary tabs') . '</h2>';
    $variables['primary']['#prefix'] .= '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">';
    $variables['primary']['#suffix'] = '</ul>';
    $output .= drupal_render($variables['primary']);
  }
  if (!empty($variables['secondary'])) {
    $variables['secondary']['#prefix'] = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('Secondary tabs') . '</h2>';
    $variables['secondary']['#prefix'] .= '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">';
    $variables['secondary']['#suffix'] = '</ul>';
    $output .= drupal_render($variables['secondary']);
  }

  return theme_menu_local_tasks($variables);
}
```

Although, this never seems to be get called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following function in template.php and called it instead or render($tabs) in the page template:

```
function {{proj}}_render_nav_tabs() {
    $output = '';

    if ($primary = menu_primary_local_tasks()) {
        $output .= '<ul class="nav nav-tabs space-bottom">' . drupal_render($primary) . '</ul>';
    }

    if ($secondary = menu_secondary_local_tasks()) {
        $output .= '<ul class="nav nav-tabs space-bottom">' . drupal_render($secondary) .'</ul>';
    }

    return $output;
}
```